# HTML not rendering when performing PHP function on load

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've created a password reset page in PHP.
I have a function at the top of the PHP page (ignore the sql escape stuff.. i've made it simple on purpose - obviously the real code is escaped as it should be).
When I DON'T call the sql check function.. the html displays as it should.
For some reason when it's finished this function, it's just spitting out the html at the bottom as text instead of processing it.

```
<?php

include "iosql.php"; // custom sql class

if (!isset($_GET["token"])) {
    die("invalid token");
}

$_token = $_GET["token"];

// here.. i have a custom class that i've created and called autoSQL. It works exactly as it should do, the code is syntactically correct.. etc.

$_check = new autoSQL();
$_check->sql = "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE password_token = '$_token' LIMIT 1";
$_check->performSQL();

// now we can check the row count:

if ($_check->sqlnumrows == 0) {
    die("invalid token");
}

// if we get here.. it means we have a valid token..
// the annoying thing is.. the page is displaying the HTML (below) as text and not rendering it!

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Password Reset</title>
</head>
<body>

The contents of my body here..

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you paste here code of iosql.php?

Comment: is it $_check->sql = "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE password_token = '$_token' LIMIT 1";  OR $_check->sql ( "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE password_token = '$_token' LIMIT 1");

Comment: for sure @Shujaat .. https://pastebin.com/raw/Qux7kgpB

Comment: isn't token Unique ? ifit is unique, no need to use LIMIT 1

Comment: it's unique and nope.. probably don't need to use the limit.. but.. the issue is that the HTML is not rendering.. not the sql stuff

Comment: enable //ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); in your iosql.php and see what errors are shown...

Comment: Can you add die('test'); before first line which is include "iosql.php"; 
Please paste here your output

Comment: Just solved it.. the iosql.php file for some reason had to be in the same directory?.. before it was in "../classes/iosql.php" (imported correctly) that's weird

Answer (score 0):

You should save your file like this test.php and if it does not work probably this issue must be related to your first line of html part. Change it will be worked.

Comment: when i removed the sql function.. the html displays as it should - the php even checks if the token exists and does die() if not.